# How can I write unit tests for WatchKit?

Tags: swift, xcode8, watchkit

I want to write unit tests for my WatchKit app extension, but I'm not sure how it should be done. According to [this](https://www.raywenderlich.com/94672/watchkit-faq) faq I should be able to add a test target for the extension, but in the template panel I can only see 'iOS Unit Testing Bundle'. If I create one, I have no idea how to proceed from there. The project won't build because of a linker error `<unit test build path> compiled with newer version of Swift language (3.0) than previous files (2.0) for architecture x86_64`. Without the test target the project builds fine. I'm using Xcode 8.2.1